# Passagem de valores pela variável não funciona

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

estou usando o framework MDL(google) para fazer um sistema de cadastro, e na parte de alterar as informações no banco de dados, na passagem dos valores pela url, apenas alguns são passados e outros não. Além disso, o nome e sobrenome de não aparecem, no formulario, embora a url tenha recebido os dois. 
Eis o código:
pagina que mostra os dados(clientes.php):

```
    $seleciona="select * from cadastro_clientes";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$seleciona);
        while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "
         <tr>
        <td class=mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric>$reg[nome]</td>
        <td class=mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric>$reg[endereco]</td>
        <td class=mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric>$reg[numero]</td>
        <td class=mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric>$reg[dada_comemorada]
        </td>
        <td class=mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric>
        <a href=form_edit.php?ru="
        .urlencode($reg['nome']).
        "&en=".urldecode($reg['endereco']).
        "&nu=".urldecode($reg['numero']).
        "&da=".urldecode($reg['dada_comemorada']).
        ">Editar</a></td>
        </tr>";
                }

                ?>
```

pagina que deve mostrar os dados para alterar(form_edit.php):

```
       <?php
       include"conecta.inc";
       $recebenome=$_GET['ru'];
       $recebeendereco=$_GET['en'];
       $numero=$_GET['nu'];
       $data=$_GET['da'];
       ?>


     <div class="page-content">
            <form action="cadastrar.php" method="post" name="cadastro">
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="nome" value=<?php echo $recebenome;?>>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">NOME</label>
              </div><br>
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="endereco" value=<?php echo $recebeendereco;?>>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">ENDEREÇO</label>
              </div><br>
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="numero" value=<?php echo $numero;?>>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">NUMERO</label>
              </div><br>
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="data" value=<?php echo $data;?>>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">DATA COMEMORADA</label>
              </div><br>

                <input type="submit" value="SALVAR" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">

            </form>

          </div>
```

na url o nome e sobrenome passa, mas não aparece no formulario, e o numero e data dão o erro "Notice: Undefined index: nu in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bjorn\form_edit.php on line 5", mas se eu cadastro algum cliente sem espaço, todos aparecem normalmente. Eu não sei o porque disso, já que eu usei urlencode :/

notem, quando eu clico no cliente que está sem escritos sem separar as palavras por espaço:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora quando eu clico no cliente cadastrado com espaços separando o nome e sobrenome, e o endereço(reparem que a url recebe o nome e sobrenome, mas não o endereço completo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `Undefined index: nu` significa que `$_GET['nu'];` está não existe, o que significa  que não existe um parametro no url (query string) para `nu`

Comment: mas por que quando eu cadastro um cliente sem usar os espaços o parâmetro é achado normalmente?

Comment: Dê um exemplo dos dois url's, quando é apanhado e quando não é

Comment: por exemplo, se eu cadastro o nome como "JonDoe", ele pega todos os dados e mostra normalmente, entretanto, se cadastro como "Jon Doe", com o uso de espaços, o formúlário só mostra "Jon", embora na url mostre que a página recebeu "Jon Doe", mas no numero e data de nascimento não aparecem, aparece o erro citado acima

Comment: No edit está `<a href=form_edit.phpru=`. Não deveria ser `<a href=form_edit.php?ru=`. No entato sugiro mesmo copiar e colar o url quando funciona e quando não funciona  para a pergunta para que seja claro o problema e para que se possa replicar o mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões atualizei o post colocando as imagens. Eu verifiquei o código na parte que você falou, e ele esta correto no meu documento, não sei por que está errado aqui, eu devo ter apagado sem querer

Comment: Pelo que vejo o url de edit não está a ser construído com todos os valores, mas apenas os 2 primeiros. Eu começava por confirmar que a variável `$reg` tem os valores que o se pretende com `print_r($reg)` exatamente antes do link de edit

Comment: Primeiro: a lista é exibida com todos os links corretos? Se algum link não ficou certo, são os que possuem espaços? Segundo: os detalhes funcionam apenas quando o link está certo ou há registros que o link está certo mas os detalhes não são exibidos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira providencia é colocar URLENCODE para todos os parâmetros.

```
<a href=form_edit.php?ru="
.urlencode($reg['nome']).
"&en=".urlencode($reg['endereco']).
"&nu=".urlencode($reg['numero']).
"&da=".urlencode($reg['dada_comemorada']).
">Editar</a>
```

E a segunda providencia é na pagina (form_edit.php):

> O espaço se tornará um separador de atributo e tudo depois do espaço será visto como atributo do elemento input.

**A solução é abraçar com aspas todos os values dos inputs:**

exemplo  `value="<?php echo $recebenome;?>"`

`<input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="nome" value="<?php echo $recebenome;?>">`

> Se você verificar o código fonte - **sem as aspas nos values** - verá que os inputs estão com os dados inseridos corretamente, porém na visualização da página só aparece a 1ª parte e é somente essa parte que será submetida para a pagina `cadastrar.php`.

```html
<input type=text id=sample3 name=endereco value=Fulano de Tal>

<input type=text id=sample3 name=endereco value="Fulano de Tal">
```

> Outro exemplo: imagine que meu nome seja `Fulano style=color:red` para passar corretamente meu nome tem que abraçar com aspas caso contrario `style=color:red` vai ser interpretado como atributo do elemento input.

```html
<input type=text id=sample3 name=endereco value="Fulano style=color:red">

<input type=text id=sample3 name=endereco value=Fulano style=color:red>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Os problemas eram exatamente esses!